# SQL Server Replication Data Folder Security Permissions

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, replication

I cannot get a snapshot to generate and the log reader to operate without granting full control of the repldata folder to the user group Everyone, which seems like the most insecure setting possible.

I am creating a WPF application to set up SQL Server Replication using [RMO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146869.aspx) and [SMO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx). My arrangement is Publisher and Distributor on one computer, Subscriber on another with Push Transactional Replication. I am using windows authenticated users as the snapshot and log_reader agents. They are given db_owner of each replicated database, and db_owner and replmonitor on the distribution database. They each have the sysadmin server role.

If I grant the snapshot and log_reader windows users and the sqlserveragent user full control of the repldata folder, the replication still fails. The error is simple, OS Error 5: Access is Denied.

Is there a more restricted user group I can grant full control to, or am I forgetting a user to grant full control to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are getting OS Error 5: Access is denied because you have not granted the Distribution Agent read permissions on the snapshot share.  You mentioned you granted permission to the Snapshot and Log Reader Agent, but not the Distribution Agent.

For a push subscription, the Distribution Agent must at minimum be a member of the **db_owner** fixed database role in the distribution and subscription database, be a member of the PAL, and have read permissions on the snapshot share.  There are also other considerations which are covered in ***Permissions That Are Required by Agents*** in [Replication Agent Security Model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151868.aspx).

Comment: Is the Distribution Agent the same as the Sql Server Agent? I see in the Transaction Publication in the PAL a user called distributor_admin, is this the Distributor? In Agent Security there is no box for Distributor so I cannot easily identify the agent.

Comment: It depends on how you configured the push subscription.  You can choose to "Run under the following Windows account" or "Run under the SQL Server Agent service account".  You can check the subscription properties under "Agent process account" to verify.

Comment: The snapshot reader is not able to read the logs, but my original problem was solved. I was able to use the functions found [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms147345(v=sql.105).aspx).